# connection reset by peer error occurs randomly

Tags: postgresql, go, error-handling

We've had a strange problem for quite some time now. We have go fucn which pings the database once per minute. Ping is just Select 1. And occasionally this ping returns an error `EXTRA *os.SyscallError=read: connection reset by peer`. This may be a couple of times a day or so. At the same time, there are no problems with the operation of the database either before or after this error. There is no logic in its occurrence either.

```
go func() {
    for range time.NewTicker(time.Minute).C {
        err := newDatabase.Ping()
        if err != nil {
            logging.Errorf("Error on DB ping", err)
        } 
    }
}
```

I studied the information about when this error occurs, and I also do not see any logic here. I understand that it is probably difficult to give an answer according to this description, but maybe someone has a similar experience

Comment: *"Ping is just Select 1"* -- are you using the [builtin ping](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.18.2#DB.Ping), or is that "Ping is just Select 1" your implementation? If it is, show its Go code.

Comment: @mkopriva Just  `result, err := db.Db.Exec("SELECT 1")
 if err != nil {
  return err
 }`

Comment: Are you creating a new connection on each ```newDatabase.Ping()```  call? I am wondering if this is because you have used maximum pool and postgres is unable to connect any more?

Comment: @AlexandrT your implementation seems innocuous enough, however note that `Exec` is generally intended for queries that [do NOT return rows](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.18.2#DB.Exec) and `SELECT 1` *does* return a row. So perhaps the problem is with using `Exec`+`SELECT`. Why not use the [builtin ping](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.18.2#DB.Ping) though? Why don't you use the right tool for the job?

Comment: @Eddie023 No, we have a database singleton that is used for all requests, and pings occur on it

Comment: This doesn't answer your exact question, but networks are inherently unreliable. My $0.02 are that your time is maybe better spent dealing with that kind of failure gracefully in your application instead of hunting down a failure that occurs in 0.x% of the cases (which doesn't sound unreasonable)

Comment: i d monitor the health of the pg pool https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/v10/internal/pool/pool.go#L385 and pprf output. the sql driver tries pretty hard to get a conn https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.2:src/database/sql/sql.go;l=846;drc=7791e934c882fd103357448aee0fd577b20013ce

Comment: @Eddie023 I thought that we really have few database connections and in theory, at peak load, they probably could not be enough (I don’t know by what logic postgres creates additional connections) But I tried to do it locally and if there are no connections available, another error is returned `53300 too_many_connections`. So why did you decide that `connection reset by peer` could be caused by the same?

Comment: What gets reported in the db servers log file?

Comment: @jjanes I found the same error in the postgres log: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer, although it does not coincide with the debug of our server in time.

Comment: @jjanes 
Before this error, you can also often see: "unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction", or "incomplete start packet", or "connection timed out".